# What is the exact need for JNI?

Tags: java-native-interface

Why do we need JNI to access the native when we can develop the entire application in JAVA.

Regards,
Sujanian

Comment: JNI is for things you _can't_ do in Java (those exist), or can do in Java but can do more efficiently in native code.

Answer (score 0):

JNI is needed, when you can't develop the entire application in Java. This can happen for example, when there is a legacy library only available in C or when there is a need to communicate with a system driver. If you can write the whole application in pure Java, you of course don't need JNI.

Answer (score 0):

When you can develop the whole application in pure Java, you do not need JNI. That is the preferred way, too.

However:

- you may want to call into existing native code libraries. It may be possible to rewrite them in Java, but that could be a lot of work (in the port and in maintaining two versions later on)
- you may need to write some low-level code to talk to the hardware/OS directly in ways that the JVM does not let you

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we need JNI to access the native when we can develop the entire
>   application in JAVA.

If by this you are asserting that you can always develop the entire application in Java, you are incorrect. You can't always do that, and JNI is there to cover the gap.

If on the other hand you mean 'if' instead of 'when', the answer is that you don't need JNI in those cases.